# How to replace result set column value from null to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query in which i have retrieved data from multiple tables and results come correct. In the output "Date" column have Null values, now i want to update the output table in a way that the null values of Date field replaced by string. I don't know the output table name created by query, i tried table0, but in vain.

I tried

"update Table0 SET  ActualStartDate='N/A' where ActualStartDate is NULL"

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to show `'N/A'` when there is null in date type column in select query  for that

```
select ISNULL(cast( UpdateDate as  nvarchar),'N/A') from ImageGallery
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it as below.

DECLARE @Sold TABLE
(SoldID VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Sold
SELECT Null UNION ALL
SELECT '1x1a' UNION ALL
SELECT '2x1c'

SELECT ISNULL(SoldID,'') AS 'SoldID' FROM @Sold